# Upper bound on $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

are there any analytical upper bounds on
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
Clearly, one upper bound is $N$. But there has to be a better one. There is an approach with Harmonic number but it's not "analytic".
Thank you

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeries.html, where the Euler-Mascheroni constant is mentioned for this.

Comment: What do you mean by an "analytic" bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard answer is $$\ln N+\gamma+\frac{1}{2N}$$ But I believe that with some effort that can be improved to $$\ln N+\gamma+\frac{1}{2N+\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: That is a fairly good result, because there is a lower bound that is similar but with $\frac{1}{3}$ replaced by $\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: could please put reference where you got this? thanks

Comment: There are some references here. I think the original result was in a Chinese journal. http://www.ajmaa.org/RGMIA/papers/v6n2/harmonic-ser.pdf

Answer (score 5):

$\sum_{n=1}^N {1 \over n} \le 1+ \ln N$.

This follows from $\int_{n-1}^n {1 \over t} dt = \ln n - \ln (n-1) > {1 \over n}$.